# Jtabbed panes not working (Gone through questions at overflow -non of them helping)

Tags: java, swing

*SHORT VERSION*

To put a long story short.I wanted to create 4 tabbedpanes and put several jpanels on the tabbedpanes.I asked a question on stack overflow on how to do this and was directed  to a certain oracle website:https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html
I found the code very convinient and used it......but it doesnt seem to be working.First off there should be 4tabbedpanes but it displays only3.And even for the 3 tabbedpanes it does not diplay the many jpanels I have placed on each one of them but instead it just displays a blank page for the three tabbedpanes that actually work.
If you have understood my problem you can just skip the *long version* story and go to *the code* part.
I have not included the code for the other 3 tabbed panes simply because I believe that If someone can find find a solution for the first pane and how to make it diaplay I'ts components I 'll easily figure out how to fix the others.
The longer version is below, but you can skip it if you have already know what the problem is and found the solution.

*LONG VERSION*

Here is a picture of one of the GIUS I wanted to make.(Its how one of the tabs should look like.)

[A more detailed image of the GIU](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1kFy.jpg)

Now atleast you get it:5 jpanels on one jpanel which is Jpanel1 that is also the first pane.And all of those Jpanels nested on the Jpanel1 have their own components e.g buttons,labbels and jtextarea.
I have placed this pictures here so that you can get a very clear idea of what I am doing and so that the problem I am having may be more clearly explained.
My tabbed panes(which are the panel1,panel2,panel3 and panel4) dont seem to be showing the jpanels I have connected to them.I used the code from:
to create the tabbedpanes.I havent included the code for the others:2,3,4  because I believe if we solve only for panel1 it will be very easy to figure out the others.The panes should be 4 of them as shown in my code, here:

```
   tabbedPane.addTab("Tab 1", icon, panel1, "Put in all the necessary information, thankyou");
   tabbedPane.setMnemonicAt(0, KeyEvent.VK_1);

   JComponent panel2=makeTextPanel("Panel #2");
   tabbedPane.addTab("Tab 2", icon, panel2, "Put in all the necessary information, thankyou");
   tabbedPane.setMnemonicAt(1, KeyEvent.VK_2);


   JComponent panel3=makeTextPanel("Panel #3");
   tabbedPane.addTab("Tab 3", icon, panel3, "Put in all the necessary information, thankyou");
   tabbedPane.setMnemonicAt(2, KeyEvent.VK_3); 

   JComponent panel4=makeTextPanel("Panel #4");
   panel4.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(450,50));     
   tabbedPane.addTab("Tab 4", icon, panel4, "Put in all the necessary information, thankyou");
   tabbedPane.setMnemonicAt(3, KeyEvent.VK_4);
```

The to each of those 4panes I have added 5jpanels,then onto those jpanels I have added other jpanels then onto those jpanells I have added the jlabels, jbuttons,jtext area and the like.

*EDIT*:Since I've been told to shorten my code and I'll shorten it, but if someone might want some clarification I'll post a longer version of the code

*SHORT VERSION OF CODE

*THE CODE*

```
public class StayConnected {
public static void main(String[] args) {

  //We have created a jframe
   JFrame frame=new JFrame ("StayConnect");
   frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   Container contentPane= frame.getContentPane();
   frame.setVisible(true);

 //Now we are creating tabbed panes which will have the different Jpanel screens.
  // ImageIcon icon =new ImageIcon("images-10.jpeg");
   JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
   ImageIcon icon =new ImageIcon("images-17.jpeg");
   contentPane.add(tabbedPane);


  //Now we are adding the jpanels to the tabbed panes.

   JComponent panel1=makeTextPanel("Panel #1");
   tabbedPane.addTab("Tab 1", icon, panel1, "Put in all the necessary information, thankyou");
   tabbedPane.setMnemonicAt(0, KeyEvent.VK_1);

   //This are other panes whose codes I have not included so you can just remove them because the issue here is with the first pane above( but if possible please include answers that are flexible enough to allow additions of more panes like the one's below.)
   JComponent panel2=makeTextPanel("Panel #2");
   tabbedPane.addTab("Tab 2", icon, panel2, "Put in all the necessary information, thankyou");
   tabbedPane.setMnemonicAt(1, KeyEvent.VK_2);


   JComponent panel3=makeTextPanel("Panel #3");
   tabbedPane.addTab("Tab 3", icon, panel3, "Put in all the necessary information, thankyou");
   tabbedPane.setMnemonicAt(2, KeyEvent.VK_3); 

   JComponent panel4=makeTextPanel("Panel #4");
   panel4.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(450,50));     
   tabbedPane.addTab("Tab 4", icon, panel4, "Put in all the necessary information, thankyou");
   tabbedPane.setMnemonicAt(3, KeyEvent.VK_4);


   contentPane.add(tabbedPane);  

   //Now we are going to add jpanels to our jpanels above. 
   //Now we are going to add jpanels to our panes above

 // **This are  the Jpanels for the first pane which is "panel1" **

    JPanel panellogo= new JPanel();
    panellogo.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    panel1.add(panellogo);

    JLabel label1= new JLabel("Dance");
    label1.setIcon(new ImageIcon("images.png"));
    panellogo.add(label1);

    //I'll stop my code here since I've been told to shorten it.But just like I said in the edit :if you want more clarification just tell me
//That code Is through for the first tab, and every other jpanel you have seen in this code has been placed on it.The tab is:"panel1


protected Component makeTextPanel(String text) {
JPanel panel = new JPanel(false);
JLabel filler = new JLabel(text);
filler.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
panel.add(filler);
return panel;
    frame.pack();
}}
```

Comment: Too. Much. Code. Please condense into a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Okay I'll make a shorter version of the code

Comment: We will probably also need to see the code of the `makeTextPanel` method. If I replace it with just a `new JPanel()`, it works for me - The nested components are being added to `panel1`. But, as already mentioned, a [mcve] would be the best.

Comment: The site  which I was linked to:https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html   didnt give that bit of information about the "makeTextPanel method.And what do you mean "replace it with just a new JPanel()"

Comment: `..didnt give that bit of information about the "makeTextPanel method.` - of course it does. You can download the complete code from the tutorial. The tutorial is a simple example. It is us to you to create the custom custom panels you will need for each tab.

Comment: I found the method added it to the code above but its still not working

Comment: Quite a few compilation errors in your posted code. Fix them please.

Comment: Also, you don't need a short version and a long version of an explanation. You need the exact details of what you are trying to do, what you have, what's not working and what you tried to do in order to make it work.

Comment: Okay, I added the method but now I keep getting this error:"Type mismatch:cannot convert Component to JComponent"  What do I do now? do I have to turn some of my components to pop up menus?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is not displaying like you want to because you are not explaining that, but I fixed some trivial compilation errors and now it looks like this:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
public class StayConnected {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("StayConnect");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();

        JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("images-17.jpeg");
        contentPane.add(tabbedPane);

        JPanel panel1 = makeTextPanel("Panel #1");
        tabbedPane.addTab("Tab 1", icon, panel1, "Put in all the necessary information, thankyou");
        tabbedPane.setMnemonicAt(0, KeyEvent.VK_1);

        JPanel panel2 = makeTextPanel("Panel #2");
        tabbedPane.addTab("Tab 2", icon, panel2, "Put in all the necessary information, thankyou");
        tabbedPane.setMnemonicAt(1, KeyEvent.VK_2);

        JPanel panel3 = makeTextPanel("Panel #3");
        tabbedPane.addTab("Tab 3", icon, panel3, "Put in all the necessary information, thankyou");
        tabbedPane.setMnemonicAt(2, KeyEvent.VK_3);

        JPanel panel4 = makeTextPanel("Panel #4");
        tabbedPane.addTab("Tab 4", icon, panel4, "Put in all the necessary information, thankyou");
        tabbedPane.setMnemonicAt(3, KeyEvent.VK_4);

        JPanel panellogo = new JPanel();
        panellogo.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
        panellogo.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        panel1.add(panellogo);

        JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Dance");
        label1.setIcon(new ImageIcon("images.png"));
        label1.setOpaque(true);
        label1.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        panellogo.add(label1);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    protected static JPanel makeTextPanel(String text) {

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.RED);
        JLabel filler = new JLabel(text);
        filler.setOpaque(true);
        filler.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        filler.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
        panel.add(filler);
        return panel;
    }
}
```

**Notes:**

- `setVisible` should be called last because you can't change the GUI simply after it is displayed.
- I added colors so you can see where each component is. It's generally a useful thing to do with GUIs.
- I specified that the tab components are `JPanel`s because this is what you are creating in the `makeTextPanel` method.

Comment: Thanks but what about the:"Type mismatch:cannot convert Component to JComponent" error I mentioned in my previous comment

Comment: @james23 I don't have it because as I said, I fixed trivial compilation errors. You should really read the documentations on Swing components.